# Tax consequences of short term capital losses

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gain, capital-loss

How do short term capital losses figure into taxable income?  If someone has 50k of taxable income before considering capital gains (and losses) and a total of $2k in short-term capital losses, what is the tax consequence?  I understand I'm asking for a simplified answer, but I want to understand the basic principle.

1. The short term capital losses only offset other capital gains, so
   if there are no capital gains, the taxable income is still $50k.
2. The short term capital losses reduce taxable income to $48k.
3. Something entirely different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capital losses offset capital gains. If you have long term capital gains - your short term losses will offset them. After that - total capital losses (if your gains are less than your losses) offset your general income up to a certain level ($3000 for a single person). If you still have losses remaining that are above that level - you carry them over to the next year and repeat the offsetting and carrying over until you've offset all the losses.

[IRS Publication 550](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p550/ch04.html#en_US_2011_publink100010713).

So in your example, assuming you only have $2K capital losses and no gains - it would be the choice number 2: you offset your income and pay taxes on $48K.