# What are tax implications of short vs long term capital losses?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-loss, schedule-d

I have read in multiple places that you can use investment losses of up to $3,000/year against your taxes.

- Is this as a deduction or credit? Does it count as an addition to itemized deductions or is it a separate deduction?
- Are short vs long term losses any different for tax purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Related**: [Tax consequences of short term capital losses](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14156/tax-consequences-of-short-term-capital-losses?rq=1)

The net capital loss is a deduction, not a credit, and it is a separate item (Schedule D) from your standard deduction, meaning you can take the standard deduction and also deduct up to $3,000 in capital losses.

The nature of the loss (short-term or long-term) is used to calculate your net capital gain.

> If you have long-term gains in excess of your long-term losses, you have a net capital gain to the extent your net long-term capital gain is more than your net short-term capital loss, if any.

References:

1. [IRS Topic 409](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc409.html)
2. [IRS Publication 550](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p550/index.html)
3. [littleadv's answer to above-linked question](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/14157/14835)